# Thread loop - Extending Thread Class Java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I need to write an Application that extends the Thread class. My class accepts an integer(i.e. 100) when it is instantiated.  `(MyThread myt = new MyThread(100); )`
This integer number will be the number of times that this class loops and prints a message.  The message should read  “The Thread is running… 100”. The 100 would be whatever number I passed into the constructor.  If the number was 150, then the output should read “ The Thread is running… 100”.  I should use a main method to test this class.  In the main I will start 2 Threads, one Thread with 150 and one Thread with 200.  I don't need to use the `sleep()` method for this code.

I already wrote a code, but I'm confused. Should my message be printed 100 times? I'm not sure if my code meets all requisites.
I should also implement this code changing this class to use the Runnable Interface instead of Thread class

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private int numtimes;

    public MyThread(int numtimes) {
        this.numbtimes = numbtimes;

    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < numbtimes; i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread Running..." + numbtimes);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyThread mytr1 = new MyThread(150);
        mytr1.start();

        MyThread mytr2 = new MyThread(200);
        mytr2.start();
    }

}
```

Is that what was asked? How would you do using Runnable Interface?

Comment: *If the number was 150, then the output should read “ The Thread is running… 100”* - That's strange

Comment: *Should my message be printed 100 times?* yes/no/ask your teacher

Comment: finally,in this trivial example without a sleep, the first thread will consume all cpu and finish before the second one begins

Comment: Yes, I used the 100 because the example was using this number... The hypothesis explanation was considering the number was 100.
Of course I asked him, but he didn't answer. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: *but he didn't answer.* - I feel for you.  BTW, my third comment is the one you pay most attention to ;-)

Comment: Actually we I run this code, they run simultaneously at the beginning. I have: Thread Running...150
Thread Running...200
Thread Running...200
Thread Running...200
Thread Running...200
Thread Running...150
Thread Running...200
Thread Running...150 and so it goes... But, yes, the first one finishes before the second one...

Comment: Wombat, have you only got a single CPU in your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two way you can use. Actually the same kind. but I prefer lambda

```
public class StackOverFlowDemo {

/**
 * one
 * */
public static class MyRun implements Runnable {
    private int numtimes;

    public MyRun(int numtimes) {
        this.numtimes = numtimes;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numtimes; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Thread(%s) Running... numtimes(%d), current count (%d) ",
                    Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                    numtimes, i));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * another way
 * */
public static void print(int numtimes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numtimes; i++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Thread(%s) Running... numtimes(%d), current count (%d) ",
                Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                numtimes, i));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /**
     * one
     * */
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRun(150), "thread 1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRun(200), "thread 2");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    /**
     * another way
     * */
    new Thread(() -> StackOverFlowDemo.print(150), "t1").start();
    new Thread(() -> StackOverFlowDemo.print(200), "t2").start();
}
```

}

Comment: This is a better answer, but why not use `System.out.format`

Comment: ok, i got it thanks ^_^. usually I use slf4j with lombok @slf4j annotation in real project,so do not know System.out.format